# listview lag with createVideoThumbnail

Tags: java, android, listview

This is custom adapter class for show video thumbnail in listview

I try to add VideoFetcherTask into asyncTask but on scrolling thumbnail change continue please help me, also I try to store data of thumb before load but still it's getting problem.

```
public class VideoAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public VideoAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;

    }

    public void setData (Cursor data){
        if (data != null) {
            changeCursor(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_item, parent, false);
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        TextView tvName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.video_display_name);
        final ImageView thumbnailView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
        ));
        //todo remove code duplication - already exists in FileChooserActivity
        final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        final String path = cursor.getString(column_index);
        final Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

        tvName.setText(displayName);
        thumbnailView.setContentDescription(displayName);
        thumbnailView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
}
```

I implement like this.  I give null on create after some permission and execute videofetcher async task to load all video from device and its work charm but on scroll device is highely leg

```
videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(this, null);
videoList.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
VideoFetcherTask.execute(1,0);
public class VideoFetcherTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Cursor>
  {
    private CursorLoader videoLoader;

    String[] projections = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE};

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        videoLoader = new CursorLoader(FileChooserActivity.this, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projections,
                null, // Return all rows
                null, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " DESC");
    }

    public Cursor doInBackground(Integer... params){
            return videoLoader.loadInBackground();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        super.onPostExecute(cursor);
        videosCursor = cursor;
        if (emptyVideoList != null) {
            emptyVideoList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        videoAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an image-loading library, like Picasso, that can generate video thumbnails asynchronously. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/VideoList

Comment: So use Glide or Picasso. There are simple APIs that act as a medium as well.

Comment: Thank you Glide is working with it